# Would a bidirectional exchange of data between two hosts, one using TCP Reno and the other using TCP Tahoe, be possible?

Tags: tcp, congestion

I know Reno and Tahoe are TCP congestion control algorithms and one recovers much faster than the other when a packet is lost, but would they affect how data are exchanged between the hosts? Bidirectional meaning that both Hosts can send and receive data from the other one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> would they affect how data are exchanged between the hosts?

No. They're just different algorithms implementing the exact same TCP protocol.

Comment: So, if they don't affect data exchange, it is, in fact, possible to have a bidirectional exchange of data between the two hosts? Because, like you said, they're implementing the same TCP protocol which is bidirectional

Comment: It's TCP, so there's a bilateral socket.